# Why can't Intellisense find variables from a header file when including it into a namespace?

Tags: c++, intellisense

First of all thank you for taking the time to read and maybe answer this.

I want to include a compressed font, which has been converted from a `.ttf` file into a `.h` file.

The compressed font is saved (in the `.h` file) inside an array of the type:

```cpp
static const unsigned int font_name_compressed_data[about 3 - 10 thousand]
```

For what I am using (ImGui) this is all fine and I can import the font correctly.

The problem is, when i want to encapsulate those `font_name_compressed_data` arrays (one for each font) within an namespace, intellisense suddenly stops recognizing them.

It still compiles fine, but intellisense does not work and it constantly shows that there are still errors.

---

I am using c++17 although i don't think that matters.
And I am compiling with Visual Studio 2019, while editing with Visual Studio Code.

Did I do it wrong the first time or is this a bug from intellisense?

**~~ E D I T :**

My assumption was wrong, after manually opening every `font_name.hpp` file and individually adding the namespace to it, intellisense was working again. But after closing and reopening it, the same error came back. It is either this

`namespace "Fonts" has no member "roboto_compressed_data"`

or this

`name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`

seemingly random.

If I autocomplete `Fonts::` in Visual Studio 2019 I get all my fonts, but if I do the same thing in Visual Studio Code I dont get any, unless I manually open the font header file in Visual Studio Code and close it again.
Also the error comes back after doing `Rescan Workspace`.

I think I have my project set up right, since I don't get an error anywhere else when using namespaces or includes.

Seems like VS Code just unloads the font header file from memory or something, since it is pretty long, but I don't know...

---

When i do it like this it does not get recognized:

in the compressed_font.h

```cpp
static const unsigned int font_name_compressed_data[size of the array] = 
{ 0x0000bc57, 0x00000000, 0x78b30000, ... and so on }
```

where i then want to use it (.cpp):

```cpp
namespace font_data
{
  #include "compressed_font.h"
}

// ...

//         v--- This is then unrecognized
font_data::font_name_compressed_data
```

---

But after i changed everything to this it got recognized again:

in the compressed_font.h

```cpp
namespace font_data
{

  static const unsigned int font_name_compressed_data[size of the array] = 
  { 0x0000bc57, 0x00000000, 0x78b30000, ... and so on }

}
```

where i then want to use it (.cpp):

```cpp
#include "compressed_font.h"

// ...

//         v--- This is now recognized
font_data::font_name_compressed_data
```

Comment: already tried the "rescan solution" command after the changes?

Comment: Your namespace should really be in the header file as you find out. Otherwise, it is hard to ensure that the same namespace is used every time and you have code duplication every time you need to include the file. Having said that, IntelliSense is less powerful than the actual compiler (essentially, a simplified model to reduce parsing overhead while working well for the majority of cases)

Comment: @Federico Yes, I also tried reinstalling the c++ extensions for VS Code but nothing changed. Luckily I found out it works the other way like I described.
I was just confused because I thought both ways would yield the same result, even though it does not (at least not always) like Phil1970 described.
Thank you :)